# I don't have the access to my server Tomcat 9 externally

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, virtual-machine, tomcat9

I'm working on implementing the solution named Apache Guacacmole but to do that I need a server Apache Tomcat
I'm actually on Debian 10 and I installed Tomcat 9.0.45
I've already configure the server and it works but only locally,
I'm on a VM for my server, and when i try to connect to my tomcat using http://myIPaddress:8080 I actually have a timedout error,

I've checked all the help and all the documentation on Apache tomcat 9 but I can't find a solution
I don't have a firewall which block the 8080 port and the connector have the configuration to let all IP access to the server.

If you can help me, well, Thank u !

Comment: Have you configured the network-interface of your VM correctly? I.e. does it allow connections and is that port 8080 open? Or even already in use?

Comment: Which VM provider is it?

Comment: @Lino Yeah it is open and in use, it correctly allow the connections... well theoretically

Comment: @Andrius Burokas I'm actually on a cluster server and i made a vm on a server from a data center

Comment: @AndriusBurokas Well that is the real problem, that is already done... i've done that when i saw that i needed to reach the VM

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind your public IP to the tomcat instance and if not check firewall settings for incoming connections.

Comment: Yeah I've done that, and my firewall settings are done too, but thanks i appreciate the help !

Comment: Do you have any other service running on the same VM ? in order to check if firewall is working properly through another -not common- port ? f.i 8090. maybe from Debian use sshd on 2222 y connect from an external network.

Comment: Well i just run the VM an i access to it with a ssh from my windows, But the ssh is on port 22 and when i do a netstat I only have my VM which listen to 0.0.0.0:8080 /java and  0.0.0.0:22 /sshd